# No records return between date range parameters

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, formula

I'm trying to modify my currently-functional report to include new fields. I want to return records where *LeavingDate* falls between two date values. I've defined *StartDate* and *EndDate* as DateTime parameters and wrote the following Select Expert formula:

```
{LeavingDate} in {StartDate} to {EndDate}
```

No records are being returned. My previous report was saved in a peculiar fashion. (The Database Expert no longer states the tables from which the report was been created. Instead it states the name of the report as the data source.) There doesn't seem to be any selection formula but it prompts for parameters and functions correctly.

I tried using the formula below instead, but to no avail:

```
not(isNull({LeavingDate})) and
{LeavingDate} in {StartDate} to {EndDate}
```

How can I get data to return?

Comment: I'm using Crystal Reports 2011, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried `{LeavingDate} >= {StartDate} AND {LeavingDate} <= {EndDate}` ?

Comment: Apologies, I should have included that - I have indeed tried that, again to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure `LeavingDate` is a dateTime value? Instead of a string or something else?

Comment: Absolutely certain; double-checked to be sure.

Comment: If I am not wrong you must be using `Business View` can you confirm?

Comment: Hi Siva, I'm not using Business View - at least not purposefully!

If it helps:

SAP BusinessObjects
CR Developer
Version 14.0.11.1696 RTM
Product Type: Full

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues with a date range recently. It sounds like your issue might be more related to your connection to the database, but this solved our date range issue:

We truncated out each attribute (year, month, day) individually and put them together, this all using the `Date()` function.

`Date(Year({d1.birthdate}), Month({d1.birthdate}), Day({d1.birthdate}))`

With this format I was then able to compare dates as expected.

Let me know if that doesn't solve it for you. In that case, we could then say the date format probably isn't the issue and move on to connection issues.

Comment: Apologies for the delay - I'm going to try this out now and will report back shortly! Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jackson, sadly this doesn't seem to resolve my particular issue.  I am presented with the 'A day number must be between 1 and the number of days in the month.' when I try to run the new formula.

Comment: Let's back up a couple steps and consider the connection issues first before we try to continue with the date idea. Might be putting the cart before the horse. Are you able to make fields that just `SELECT` columns and show their data without any restriction?

Comment: Hi Jackson, thanks for getting back to me.  I'm investigating this now as it would appear as though without any filtering, only 42 results are returned.  I think that the table links are the limiting factor.

Once I've exhausted this to no avail, I'll update here accordingly! :)

Thanks again for your help to date.

Comment: Sure, if you get a report that can pull raw data correctly and you're still having issues, let me know. That's a good ground to start from.

Comment: It actually transpires that this was resultant from some joining oddities.  Whist I'm not 100% on the resolution (I'm about 95% of the way there), it would seem that the parameters didn't have any real effect on the the record selection.

Apologies for any time wasted and endless thanks for your kindly assistance.  I hope that your answers can assist someone who is genuinely having parameter woes!

All the best,


Rob

Comment: Not at all, hakuna matata, glad you're figuring it out. Let me know if anything changes